# JSF 2.0 Update a primefaces dialog not working the first time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a simple form that asks the user to input a text. Then when the user clicks the link, a dialog is showed with the value entered by the user. The first issue I have is that the dialog does not show.

The other issue concerns the update. When the form is displayed for the first time, the HTML code is correct and the current value of `#{dialogBean.location}` is empty.

Then I click on the link, the HTML code is "wrong". That's why I guess it does not show:

```
<form id="dialogForm" name="dialogForm" method="post" action="/tcmt-component/dialog.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="dialogForm" value="dialogForm">
<input type="hidden" autocomplete="off" value="-6424900608015567042:-9068630845666043913" id="javax.faces.ViewState" name="javax.faces.ViewState"></form>
```

In the mean time, I check the return of the Ajax call. The value of `#{dialogBean.location}` is still empty.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="dialogForm:dialog"><![CDATA[<div id="dialogForm:dialog" style="display:none" title="Dialog">  
        Current Location:
```

I click again on the link and this time the value of `#{dialogBean.location}` is set to the correct value.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="dialogForm:dialog"><![CDATA[<div id="dialogForm:dialog" style="display:none" title="Dialog">  
        Current Location: MyLocation
```

The Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class DialogBean implements Serializable {

    private String location;

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

}
```

The View:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">

  <h:head> 
  </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="initForm">

        <h:inputText id="location" value="#{dialogBean.location}" />
        <p:commandLink update="dialogForm:dialog" onclick="dlg.show()">  
            <h:outputText value="Show Dialog" />  
        </p:commandLink>

        </h:form>  

        <h:form id="dialogForm">
        <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">  
        Current Location: <h:outputText value="#{dialogBean.location}" />
        <p:commandButton value="Close" oncomplete="dlg.hide();"/>
        </p:dialog>
        </h:form>  
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**SOLUTION**

It seems that it's a primefaces issue updating a dialog. Instead I wrapped the dialog inside a panel and the update works:

```
<p:dialog header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">  
<p:outputPanel id="dialogPanel">
Current Location: <h:outputText value="#{dialogBean.location}" />
    <h:form id="dialogForm">
<p:commandButton value="Close" oncomplete="dlg.hide();"/>
</h:form>  
</p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>

<h:form id="initForm">
<h:inputText id="location" value="#{dialogBean.location}" />
<p:commandLink update="dialogPanel" onclick="dlg.show()">  
    <h:outputText value="Show Dialog" />  
</p:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Comment: +1 - I experienced the same problem today with the PrimeFaces 3.0-M3-SNAPSHOT and ended up using the same solution of a `<p:outputPanel>` inside the `<p:dialog>` as an Ajax PPR target. Too bad I didn't find your solution earlier or I could have saved some time and effort! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try put the **dialog** before the **commandLink** as follows:

```
  <p:outputPanel id="panel">
       <h:form id="dialogForm">
           <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Dialog" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">  
           Current Location: <h:outputText value="#{dialogBean.location}" />
           <p:commandButton value="Close" oncomplete="dlg.hide();"/>
           </p:dialog>
       </h:form>  
 </p:outputPanel>
     <h:form id="initForm">
    <h:inputText id="location" value="#{dialogBean.location}" />
    <p:commandLink update="dialogForm:dialog" onclick="dlg.show()" update="panel">  
        <h:outputText value="Show Dialog" />  
    </p:commandLink>
    </h:form>
```

Another easy solution is : If you use the Primefaces 3.0(or above) you can add dymaic attribute to the dialog .set it to true.
Here is the primefaces 3.2's [VDL](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.2/) 
Dynamic mode allows dialog to fetch it's contents before it's shown rather than on page load which is useful to reduce initial page load times. Default is false.

Comment: It fixes the update of the dialog the first time. But still the dialog does not show up. In the log `INFO: Cannot find component with identifier "dialogForm:dialog" in view`. So I tried `:dialogForm:dialog`, it removes the INFO log but still the problem. If I put `dialog` the dialog shows up but it's not updated and I have the INFO log: `INFO: Cannot find component with identifier "dialog" in view.`

Comment: Updating a panel instead of a dialog fixes the issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should not use the update attribute.Because when u use the dlg.show(), the dialog will be updated.

Comment: The dialog is updated on show only if it is set as `dynamic=true`.

Comment: falsarella: yeah, you are right. the dynamic attribute has add since Primefaces version(3.0).

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem for the last few days, after reading this post, I just solved my problem by removing the `'layout="block"'` from my `panelGrid|outputPanel`.  I have `update="pageContentPanel"` embedded in my CRUD form pages, and now this AJAX PPR is working better.  I guess AJAX PPR (and PrimeFaces 3.0 M3) works better with `span` tags more than `div` tags.  :(

```
    <ui:define name="pageContent">

        <p:outputPanel id="pageContentPanel">

            <p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{pageNavigationController.isPageSelected('/pageContent_blank.xhtml')}">
                <ui:include src="/pageContent_blank.xhtml"/>
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{pageNavigationController.isPageSelected('/service/pf_Add.xhtml')}">
                <ui:include src="/service/pf_Add.xhtml"/>
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{pageNavigationController.isPageSelected('/service/pf_Browse.xhtml')}">
                <ui:include src="/service/pf_Browse.xhtml"/>
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{pageNavigationController.isPageSelected('/service/pf_Edit.xhtml')}">
                <ui:include src="/service/pf_Edit.xhtml"/>
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="#{pageNavigationController.isPageSelected('/service/pf_View.xhtml')}">
                <ui:include src="/service/pf_View.xhtml"/>
            </p:outputPanel>

        </p:outputPanel>

    </ui:define>
```